# Returning a different Tomcat session ID based on URI in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, embedded-tomcat-8

I'm very new to Spring + Tomcat and trying to learn it while working on an existing spring boot (v. `2.6.x`) web app running on a Tomcat server (tomcat-embed-core v. `9.0.x`).

The application serves URLs of this type:

1. ```
   \{customer}\path\to\resource
   ```
2. ```
   \{customer}\newapp\path\to\resource
   ```

I can see this reported on the `ModelAndView` controller annotated with the likes of `PostMapping` and `GetMapping`.

Now, the service keeps tracks of sessions using `JSESSION` cookies and generating session IDs using tomcat's standard `org.apache.catalina.SessionIdGenerator`.

I would like to programmatically change the format of the session identifier generated by tomcat, depending on the request being served.

Given the paths above, for instance, I'd like to have:

- request to 1. above, should be generating session identifiers like `905A6892CB2C12F84A331F58A6A2C382`
- requests to `newapp`, i.e. 2. above, should be generating session identifiers like `NEWAPP_905A6892CB2C12F84A331F58A6A2C382`

The format of the session is irrelevant, but they must have a different prefix.

It seems that one way to achieve this would be to have two different contexts, each one with a different catalina `Manager`, which can be set using `org.apache.catalina.Context#setManager`.

I'm not able to define two different contexts because the root in the path is the variable `{customer}`, nor I'm able to dynamically inject the context using an implementation of `org.apache.catalina.valves.ValveBase`, as there is no easy way to create a delegated context, where the only difference WRT the base tomcat context is the `Manager`.

I've tried changing the root of the `newapp` paths to be like `newapp\{customer}\path\to\resource` and creating a new Context for `newapp`, but this fails if I try to override `org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory#getWebServer` like

```java
@Override
public WebServer getWebServer(ServletContextInitializer... initializers) {
    Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
    File baseDir = createTempDir("tomcat");
    tomcat.setBaseDir(baseDir.getAbsolutePath());
    prepareContext(tomcat.getHost(), initializers);
    final String documentRoot = getValidDocumentRoot().getAbsolutePath();
    final Context ctx = tomcat.addContext("/newapp", documentRoot);
    ctx.setManager(new NewAppManager());
    return getTomcatWebServer(tomcat);
}
```

returning a `404` error - it looks like the application is not able to find the mapping for the path, even if I successfully changed the `GetMapping` to `newapp\{customer}\path\to\resource`.

Can anyone suggest the best way to achieve this and if what I'm trying even makes sense?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Why? The session, when used, is quite important and messing around with that will probably break things.

Comment: The application is moving to serve traffic from "oldapp" to serving it on `newapp`, which will be served on a different domain, hence will be saving cookies for a different domain than "oldapp". Changing the JSESSIONID has been set as a requirement from a different team.

Comment: If they are on a different domain, the don't share the same session...

Comment: They do not, in fact two different JSESSIONs are created, one per domain.
But the pattern of the value is exactly the same. That is what we're trying to differentiate.

Comment: Which is what I said... That they don't share a session and yes the pattern is the same as that is how Tomcat generates the session ids. You won't get the session cookie from domain x on domain y as they aren't sent as they don't belong to that domain.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that - yeah, I'm aware the sessions won't be shared across domains, but the application internals use the session IDs as keys in basically a map, so we were asked to differentiate them. I added an answer as to how I was able to solve the problem, any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the required outcome by adding a few lines in the `getWebServer` method.

Adding the whole method below, with comments, for clarity.

```java
        @Override
        public WebServer getWebServer(ServletContextInitializer... initializers) {
            Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
            File baseDir = createTempDir("tomcat");
            tomcat.setBaseDir(baseDir.getAbsolutePath());
            customizeEngine(tomcat.getEngine());
            prepareContext(tomcat.getHost(), initializers);
            // This is the ROOT context generated by the embedded tomcat
            final StandardContext rootCtx = (StandardContext) tomcat.getHost().findChild("");
            // Both context will be sharing the same war file
            final String documentRoot = getValidDocumentRoot().getAbsolutePath();
            // Creating a new context for the "newapp, serving the "/newapp" path
            final StandardContext newappCtx = (StandardContext) tomcat.addContext("/newapp", documentRoot);
            // This turned out to be very important, sets the classloader of the context to delegate to the application classloader, exactly as ROOT ctx does
            newappCtx.setParentClassLoader(rootCtx.getParentClassLoader());
            newappCtx.setDelegate(true);
            // This was needed in our specific case, the default cookie path would be "/newapp"
            newappCtx.setSessionCookiePath("/");
            // And finally setting the session manager, generating a new session identifier
            newappCtx.setManager(new NewappSessionManager());
            final WebServer ws = getTomcatWebServer(tomcat);
            // This is the default dispatcher created by the embedded tomcat
            final Servlet dispatcherServlet = ((StandardWrapper) rootCtx.findChild("dispatcherServlet")).getServlet();
            // We're now adding the default servlet to the "newappCtx"
            Tomcat.addServlet(newappCtx, "dispatcherServlet", dispatcherServlet);
            // it will serve all paths under "/newapp"
            newappCtx.addServletMappingDecoded("/*", "dispatcherServlet");
            return ws;
        }
....
        // Simple manager for the new context
        private static final class NewappSessionManager extends StandardManager {
            @Override
            protected String getNextSessionId() {
                return "NEWAPP_" + super.getNextSessionId();
            }
        }
```